# Getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Tags: karma-jasmine

Getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at

```
public/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js:2
```

I have my karma.conf.js with

```
files: [


  'public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',

  'public/lib/angular/angular.js',

  'public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

  'public/lib/**/*.js',

 'public/config.js',

 'public/application.js',

 'public/modules/core/core.client.module.js',

 'public/modules/core/controllers/c-controller.client.controller.js',

  'public/modules/core/tests/c-controller.client.controller.test.js' 

  ],
```

Comment: My issue solved by removing reference to public/lib/boostrap libraries as it is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue solved by removing reference to public/lib/boostrap libraries as it is not required.